# What is reaction time of a single c. elegans neuron?

Tags: neurophysiology, artificial-neural-network

What is the reaction time of a single c. elegans neuron?
Is sensory neuron reaction to stimulus is similar to intermediate neuron passing a signal to motor neuron? What about chemical and electrical synapses?

I want to make a simple real-time artificial network model using existing c. elegans connectome projects, but I can't find anything defining time scale.